# Increment section numbers in PDF output

Tags: latex, yaml, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to increment the section headers in my rMarkdown (PDF output) file by 1. Instead of `# First` resulting in `1 First`, I'd like `2 First.`

I found a way to define the offset in html_output using the following syntax, but it doesn't work for pdf_output.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "author"
date: "date"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    pandoc_args: [
      "--number-sections",
      "--number-offset=1"
    ]
---
# First Header
# First SubHeader
```

This results in

```
2   First Header
2.1 First Subheader
```

However, this syntax does not work for PDF documents:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "author"
date: "date"
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    pandoc_args: [
      "--number-sections",
      "--number-offset=1"
    ]
---

#   First Header
## First Subheader
```

This results in

```
1   First Header
1.1 First Subheader
```

Section headers are not incremented by 1.

According to PANDOC documentation, `number-offset` only exists for HTML documents.

> --number-offset=NUMBER[,NUMBER,…] Offset for section headings in HTML output (**ignored in other output formats**). The first number is added to
>   the section number for top-level headers, the second for second-level
>   headers, and so on. So, for example, if you want the first top-level
>   header in your document to be numbered “6”, specify --number-offset=5.
>   If your document starts with a level-2 header which you want to be
>   numbered “1.5”, specify --number-offset=1,4. Offsets are 0 by default.
>   Implies --number-sections.

How can I increment section headers in PDF documents?

Thank you!

Comment: What does "hide it" mean? Yes, you can insert LaTeX code to perform similar changes, but the question is not clear. Could you provide a sample document that would represent your input and expected output?

Comment: @Werner Apologies. This was my first post here. I've added an example and made my question more specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, [pandoc does PDF generation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf) by generating a LaTeX file first...

```
$ echo '# first' | pandoc -t latex
\section{first}\label{first}
```

To tell LaTeX to start with a different number, you can include raw TeX in your markdown document, like:

```
\setcounter{section}{2}

# my title
```