# RMarkdown with Knit to HTML: How to increase section number?

Tags: knitr, r-markdown

I am generating HTML pages with KnitR HTML from RMarkdown (using R Studio).

I need section numbering starting at an arbitrary number, not 0 or 1.

Example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
TITLE
2 SECTION
2.1 SUB-SECTION
```

I am using a code such as:

```
---
title: "TITLE"
output:
  html_document: 
    number_sections: yes
---

# SECTION

## SUBSECTION
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33395773/increment-section-numbers-in-pdf-output) asks for a PDF solution, but there is a hint on how to do it in HMTL (`--number-offset`). Does this help?

Comment: Yes it solves it, THANKS!.If you write the answer I will give it to you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33395773/2706569).

---

The `pandoc` option `--number-offset` allows to specify the "offset for section headings in HTML output":

> **--number-offset=NUMBER[,NUMBER,…]**
>
> Offset for section headings in HTML output (ignored in other output formats). The first number is added to the section number for top-level headers, the second for second-level headers, and so on. So, for example, if you want the first top-level header in your document to be numbered “6”, specify `--number-offset=5`. If your document starts with a level-2 header which you want to be numbered “1.5”, specify `--number-offset=1,4`. Offsets are 0 by default. Implies `--number-sections`.

Quoted from the [`pandoc` README file](http://pandoc.org/README.html#options-affecting-specific-writers).